# Why docker image ID may diverge after WORKDIR command?

Tags: docker

*The question arose from trying to employ docker layer caching in circle-ci, but that's probably unimportant.*

Here are two runs of docker image building in some of our CI pipelines, they produce the following log:

```
Step 1/14 : FROM node:14-buster-slim
 ---> c3c0ff217b2e
Step 2/14 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eed32bb18027
Step 3/14 : RUN mkdir ****1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87d479512fbd
```

On the other run the ID after the Step 2 is different:

```
Step 1/14 : FROM node:14-buster-slim
 ---> c3c0ff217b2e
Step 2/14 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8fb66c29a0b3
Step 3/14 : RUN mkdir ****1
 ---> Running in 44142ac5bf26
```

E.g. it used exactly the same layer `c3c0ff...` at the first step, but after applying `WORKDIR /app` it suddenly become different.

I obviously miss something - so please enlighten me why it is different (and thus preventing us to use cached one).

UPD: docker version in CI seems to be `19.03.13`

Comment: What version of Docker are you using?  Apparently this is a [known issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30081) that has supposedly been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Also, if you're using a CI system, can you be really sure each run is on the same machine and using the shared layer caching?  I don't know how it works on Circle CI but if you're using different build nodes for each build the shared caching may not be instantaneous or automatic.

Comment: @Iguananaut thanks for response and for link! Not sure about same machine - but I don't understand how it may happen that first step is producing the same image but second not. I.e. I'd think they should either both match or both differ...

Comment: @Iguananaut - I checked logs and it seems our CI uses docker `19.03.13` though I'm not sure in which version the issue by the link is fixed...